# Cordova hide screen from recent activity list on Android

Tags: android, cordova, pixi.js

Is there a way in Cordova to clear the screen before the app goes into the recent activity list on Android?

I'm making a game where I don't want the user to be able to see the playfield during a pause. So I need to switch visuals or something before the app ends up in the recent activity list.

At the moment I'm listening for the 'pause' event from Cordova, but even if I render the canvas once more at this point (or even remove it entirely) this new state won't show on the recent app list and instead still shows the previous frame.

I've seen some banking apps have this behavior so it should be possible somehow.

PS: I'm using PIXI as framework but I assume that's of no concern here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution via this blog post: https://medium.com/@lakshaydulani/hybrid-app-horror-hiding-the-screenshot-in-app-switcher-82c318a350bf

Apparently there is a Cordova plugin that does exactly what I need: https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin

Just install and compile the app.. Sweet!